# Force HTTPS on Azure and append URL

Tags: azure, url-rewriting

I'm trying to force HTTP to HTTPS on an Azure Web Site using a web.config URL rewrite rule. I'd like a rule which encompases both of the following scenarios:

HTTP: //site.domain.com/sitefolder to HTTPS: //site.domain.com/sitefolder

HTTP: //site.domain.com/sitefolder/default.aspx to HTTPS: //site.domain.com/sitefolder/default.aspx

If I follow [this guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/01/07/https-only-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx) I can force HTTP to HTTPS but the URL changes to HTTPS: //site.domain.com without the /sitefolder or /sitefolder/default.aspx appended.

This is what I've got at the moment. HTTPS is forced, but the full URL is not included:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the simple rule that makes correct redirect to HTTPS on Azure WebSites:

```
   <rule name="Redirect to https">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
```

You can test it here: http://double.azurewebsites.net (take the note on the HTTP in the link) I don't have any other rules defined here. The rule above correctly redirects to deep links, i.e. http://double.azurewebsites.net/Home/About

Comment: @MK8 take in consideration that its only for head and get (meaning not other request will be reroute to the HTTPS, like POST)

Comment: A lot of blog posts on this, but this is the only rule that actually works.

Comment: At least for me, on azure websites, this does not work. Also, the example link provide takes you to a "http" website instead of "https".... Any other ideas?

Comment: It works perfect! but... how can I modify the `<match>` so that it only applies on azurewebsites.net but not in localhost?

Comment: to answer myself, add this: `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127\.0\.0\.1(:\d+)?$" negate="true" /> `